# Void marriage petetion

Tags: india, family-law, marriage

Marsh married to suleka on 3rd Jan and this is a arranged marriage and it was forced family marriage for marsh. Again on next Feb Marsh registered perry who's his lover and both have forged witness signature of their parents by themselves . Suleka filed null and void marriage petition in the court and mentioned that Marsh Married to Perry in December hence her marriage is null and void. Marsh has paid 8lc rs to suleka already as a allymoney and decided to stay with Perry. What the judgement will be.

Will the court ask marsh to produce the witness for the marriage registration and what marsh has to answer 
Will the court again ask marsh to pay the money to suleka what marsh has to say.  Please answer

Comment: It's in India age 31.24.26

Answer (score -2):

Here the case is by the sulekha only to dissolve the marriage and declare it void . If court finds it may declare the marriage as void